# ssh not connecting and no error in verbose mode

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

I can't ssh from any machine to one of our servers (in the same network).
I try to run ssh in verbose mode but do not get any error :

```
vincent@feed01:/var/cache/feed$ ssh -vvv vincent@feed02.xxx.com
OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1 14 Mar 2012
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to feed02.xxx.com [192.168.0.161] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/vincent/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/vincent/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/vincent/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/vincent/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/vincent/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/vincent/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
```

And from that moment nothing happens, I have to Ctrl-C to regain access to the terminal.

The `auth.log` doesn't capture anything either.
We have tried from different machines, different users, same issue.

```
iptables -L INPUT -v -n | less
```

returns nothing

What could be the issue ?

Comment: the account Vincent could be locked on the other machine (e.g password field to *LK*) and you will have a similar output. (even if you have correct authentication/ssh-keys/Kerberos/whatever)

Comment: no firewall, will check the password LK lock, thanks for the tip

Comment: maybe also try to bounce the sshd daemon on the other server ? (just restart it), or maybe a filesystem full on one of the systems as well (/var for example, could block a log file being written and it would hang the connection)